# VLC HDR saturation

Tags: 20.04, vlc

Ubuntu 20.04 Wayland

```
ffprobe $IN 2>&1 | grep "Stream #0:0"
Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
```

Testing other players;

- No decoder

  - gst-play-1.0
- low saturation

  - VLC (out=X11)
  - ffplay -loglevel 16
- OK

  - MPV
  - SMPlayer (renders in separate window)

How to get VLC to show the correct saturation for HDR content?